# How to open system camera in its normal operation after I launch it from my activity?

Tags: android, camera

I am working with camera in project and provided a simple button in activity which will open camera app in my device. But the problem is after clicking one photo, it asks weather I want to keep my picture or not and after clicking yes, it return to my main activity.

But I want to operate camera in normal mode, I mean like when we click photo after photos and all that.
My code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

following permission is used

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" uses-permission
```

I dont know why tags are not working. 
Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: After click photos what you want to do ? pl elaborate your code

Comment: I dont want to do anything with photos. Just use simple camera for clicking photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take multiple photos, you should launch the intent with this action:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
startActivity(intent);
```